# How to show images using Mysaifu JVM

Tags: java, swt

I'm using Mysaify JVM on Windows 6.1 CE to run Java SWT application.

Folowing codes work fine in WIndows XP - show images on window bar (next to window title)

1.

```
setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(LoginWindow.class, "/com/stream/icons/document16.png"));
```

2.

```
Image im = new Image(null, "D:\MWS\MWS_Panel\system\icons\document16.png");
setImage(im);
```

required swt-gdip-win32-3655.dll ( Mysaifu says  .dll dont want to load this dll ;( )

I tried to load:

png, bmp, jpg, gif

with no success.

Does anyone konow solution of this problem? It's realy hard to find some informationa by Google :(

Answer (score 0):

SWT is backed on to native implementations of it's windowing toolkit, this is what is in `swt-gdip-wind32-6355.dll`, this dll in particalar is the Windows 32 (Windows NT, XP etc) implementation,

In order to use SWT on Windows CE you will need a Windows CE implementation of SWT.

You might be out of luck with SWT on Windows CE the [Wikipedia entry doesn't list it as a supported platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit#Platform_support).